# How to check Version of Yeoman Generator not hosted on npm?

Tags: yeoman-generator

Hello I have a private yeoman generator that we use internally at my company.
Right now we have people checking out the repository and run an `npm link` so we can run our generator locally.

What is the preferred way to 'phone home' to our private repo from which the generator is created so once we push it out, users can be alerted to update the generator to the latest?

Right now we just tell people to do a `git pull` from the locally checked out generator repository before creating new projects.

Comment: I actually need to know the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ops tools like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) to automatically deploy your generator on your enterprise dev machines.

If you wish to use npm infrastructure, then register for a [NPM enterprise](https://www.npmjs.com/enterprise) private repository.